# How to retrieve website names?

Tags: php, html, title

I am wondering if there is a way to get the name of a website from a URL. I know you can parse a URL to get a domain name, but since site names are not standardized as far as code is concerned, I am doubtful.

An example of how this could be used is say I am linking to a New York Times article. I can have the title of the article link to the article page. Then I might want to have the source, "The New York Times" displayed next to the title of the article. It would be exceedingly convenient if I could have this automatically generated.

Just getting the page title wouldn't work because that would usually give you the article title or, if you were to link to some other type of page, you might get some string like "How to retrieve website names? - Stack Overflow." I would only want to get the "Stack Overflow" part of that.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could try to fetch the title of the root document, e.g. `stackoverflow.com`

Comment: So you would be parsing the `url` from a different host?

Comment: You'll need to use a human. Every site does it differently, some use images which can't be read by PHP, some use meta attributes, some use the title, you can't determine it by script.

Comment: Hmm... Fetching the title of the root document might work. I think I will probably just have to create a field that I enter things into manually though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to parse the DOM tree using [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
<?php
function GetTitle($url)
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTMLFile($url); // @ supresses warnings

    // try to get meta application-name
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("meta") as $meta)
    {
        $metaName = $meta->attributes->getNamedItem("name");
        if (strtolower($metaName->nodeValue) == "application-name")
        {
            $metaContent = $meta->attributes->getNamedItem("content");
            if ($metaContent != NULL)
                return $metaContent->nodeValue;
        }
    }

    // title fallback:
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("title") as $title)
        return $title->nodeValue;

    return NULL;
}

print(GetTitle("http://www.nytimes.com/"));
?>
```

First, `GetTitle()` looks for a `<meta name="application-name">` tag. If not found, it will fallback and return the page title instead.

Additionally, you should pass the base url. F.e. if you have this url: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185145/how-to-retrieve-website-names/16185654#16185654`, you should strip everything except `http://stackoverflow.com` using [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
GetTitle($parsedUrl["scheme"] + "://" + $parsedUrl["host"]);
```

Comment: This looks pretty good. I'm not the best with PHP, though. How would I include `$parsedUrl` in `GetTitle($url)`?

Comment: And should it also look for `<meta property="og:site_name">` tag?

Comment: First: the code is already in the answer. Second: You could do that, but I bet that property is rarely used.

Comment: Okay, so if I put the code as is into my site, it beautifully displays The New York Times. I have a function that displays an article's source url, however, and if I plug that in, it doesn't retrieve any titles. Do you have any idea why that might be? I just replaced "http://www.nytimes.com/" with `the_permalink()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the application-name property:

```
<meta name="application-name" content="The New York Times" />
```

also

```
<meta name="application-name" content="CNN"/>
```

Not every site will have this but you can start here, check for open graph tags (http://ogp.me), etc.

Comment: If more sites used this, it would definitely be the solution for me. I wonder what the adoption rate has been like...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse the url, you could try this function:

```
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
$host = $parsedUrl['host']
echo $host;
```

This will give you an associative array where the `host` key is what you are looking for.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 0):

What you call 'Site name' is not a part of the link, it is part of the HTML code returned by that link.

If you want to get the site title, you should retrieve the link content using CURL and then parse the returned HTML to get the content of the  tag in the  section.

Probably this will be expensier than the benefit you could get.